Will Hotchocolate GraphQL cancel a query by just specifying a CancellationToken parameter in the resolver?
Imagine you have a resolver configured to return IQueryable allowing hotchocolate to handle the filtering, projection, sorting, etc. via EF Core integration.
Resolver:
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts([Service] IService service, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    => service.Get<Product>();

where service.Get() is just:
dbContext.Set<T>()

If such query is taking 2 minutes and while executing it, the user cancelled it; hence the question: will hotchocolate cancel its execution using the declared CancellationToken?
